# rxjs subscribe onerror binding

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Im using angular2/rxjs and having a hard time understanding the usefulness of the onerror callback for `.subscribe()`.  Every example i've seen simply prints to the console, however, what if i want to do something else, like have another service handle the error?  Simply calling `this.otherservice.handleError` doesn't get `this` bound correctly.  so then i need to call it like `this.otherservice.handleError.bind(this.otherservice)`.  Is this expected or am i missing something?

```
@Injectable
export class OtherService {
    public foo: Subject<string>;
    constructor() {
        this.foo = new Subject<string>();
    }
    handleError(error: any) {
        this.foo.next(error);
    }
}


@Injectable
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private otherservice: OtherService) {}
    get() {
        this.http.get('www.foo.com').subscribe(
            () => 'success',
            this.otherservice.handleError
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, when you put closures to subscribe, it'll convert to this form:

```
observer = {
  next: onNextFn,
  error: onErrorFn,
  complete: onCompleteFn
}
```

so when you put:

```
 .subscribe(
    () => 'success',
    this.otherservice.handleError
 )
```

this mean:

```
{
  next: () => 'success',
  error: this.otherservice.handleError
}
```

so `this` context will be `observer` object. you need bind context to maintain correct context of these function.

Comment: Thank you, after your explanation, i used the lambda syntax and that got it working as expected.  Though it's probably not much different than .bind(), it looks a little cleaner.

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score -1):

Your error method expects a parameter which you are not defining

```
get() {
    this.http.get('www.foo.com').subscribe(
        (data => 'success'}), 
    (error) => {
        this.otherservice.handleError
    )
}
```